# How to unit test with Moq the Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, moq, azure-keyvault

I need to mock the endpoint of the Key Vault in order to know if I am calling the function to get the key vault once.

I am developing this with C# and Moq (Framework) in order to do the testing.

The interface is the following:

```
public interface IKeyVaultConnection
{
    string GetKeyVaultValue(string variableName);
}
```

```
 public class KeyVaultConnection
    {
        public KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient;
        private string endpointKeyVault;

        public KeyVaultConnection(string keyVaultAddress = "DefaultEndpoint")
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            endpointKeyVault = $"https://{ keyVaultAddress }.vault.azure.net";
        }

        private async Task<string> AsyncGetSecretValue(string keyName)
        {
            var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{endpointKeyVault}/secrets/{ keyName }")
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return secret.Value;
        }

        public string GetKeyVaultValue(string variableName)
        {
            Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () => await AsyncGetSecretValue(variableName));
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
}
```

```
 Mock<IKeyVaultConnection> mock = new Mock<IKeyVaultConnection>();
//----->>>>>>   Need to setup the endpoint
 mock.Setup(x => x.GetKeyVaultValue(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
 // mock.Verify(x => x.GetKeyVaultValue(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

What I need is to fake the connection to the endpoint in order to get that I am calling that function once and I am getting errors like:

```
"KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"
```

for not providing the endpoint.

If I uncomment last line `(mock.Verify(x => x.GetKeyVaultValue(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());)`  I get this:

```
"Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: 
 x => x.GetKeyVaultValue(It.IsAny<string>())"
```

Comment: "some errors" - can you be more specific?

Comment: @stuartd edited, but is kind of errors like, you haven't provided the endpoint and so on...

Comment: Please share complete test, with sut also with the invocation as well... What `IKeyVaultWrapper` is? BTW you should not return `It.IsAny<string>()` it will be `null`. Moq doens't have knowledge to return any string, which is reasonable isn't it...

Comment: _"Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times"_ well, in the code you have provided you're not invoking it, so this is to be expected?

Comment: And the class you are testing is? I think the problem is that you use `.Returns(It.IsAny<string>())` which means that method will return null then you sut class actually complains about that...

Comment: It looks to me like you are not providing `mock.Object` as the dependency to whatever you are calling so you are calling the actual implementation. Just creating a mock does not do magic, you have to use that mock.

Comment: Unrelated, but why would you make `GetKeyVaultValue` a synchronous method that blocks?

Comment: @Crowcoder It is not synchronous ,since it waits until the promise is resolved.
And for the previous comment, how could I pass the mock.Object there, I am not quite sure how to pass that.

Comment: The Task.Run delegate is async but the public api of the method is synchronous. Wrapping the async I/O bound call in Task.Run is like buying a new car then carrying it around on the back of a flat-bed truck instead of just driving the car.

Comment: @Crowcoder How would you suggest to improve the code? I am more than happy to know about that, quite new to this :S

Comment: I would mark the method `async Task<string>` then replace the code with `return await AsyncGetSecretValue(variableName);`. Very similar to how `AsyncGetSecretValue` is written. You will of course have to refactor anything that calls it. However, to be clear, this is not related at all to your mock problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you view your class as nothing but a humble wrapper so that other classes can depend on `ISomethingThatReturnsValues` without knowing about `KeyVaultClient` then mocking `KeyVaultClient` isn't necessary. We only need to go so far. We don't need to unit test framework classes that we depend on.

In other words, do we need to verify that

```
keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{endpointKeyVault}/secrets/{ keyName }")
```

...actually calls the endpoint to get the secret? It does. That's what `KeyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(string)` does. If the test fails, what can we do? We can't fix that class. Similarly, if we followed that road to its logical conclusion, we'd have to test all sorts of stuff. When we create a `List<string>` and add a string, does it really get added? We don't test those things because they're already tested so it's reasonable to assume that they work as expected.

A good test for this would be an integration test which verifies that your class does what it expected. Or, if another class depends on this, you could write an integration test for that class which would fail if you can't retrieve anything from the key vault. But that wouldn't require any mocking.

Part of being comfortable with *not* unit testing the class is minimizing it so that it really does nothing except invoke the inner class. In this case you could collapse your `public` and `private` method into one `public` method, and maybe one more to provide an `async` option:

```
    public async Task<string> GetSecretValueAsync(string keyName)
    {
        return await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{endpointKeyVault}/secrets/{ keyName }");
    }

    public string GetSecretValue(string keyName) => GetSecretValueAsync(keyName).Result;
```

Now it's more evident: This class doesn't really do anything of its own that needs unit testing. Its useful purpose is to adapt `KeyVaultClient` to your interface - `IKeyVaultConnection` so that other classes don't directly depend on `KeyVaultClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now offers support for unit testing Azure resources using the SDK. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/